# Mesh with texture background color

Tags: three.js

I create a `Mesh` having a `PlaneGeometry` and the material defined by a texture loaded from a JPEG image. Everything is fine, excepting that there is a small amount of time before the texture image is loaded when the plane is displayed using a dark color. Is there a way to change this color to something else?

I tried the `color` option for material, but it is not applied.

```
var texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/path/to/image');
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    side : THREE.DoubleSide,
    map : texture,
    color : 0xf0f0f0
// this doesn't seem to work
});
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(Math.abs(line.x1 - line.x0), depth);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That black color is the texture rendering without any texture data. The easiest fix is to load the texture and the mesh, but do not render the mesh until both have fully loaded.

Another option is to create a very small 1x1 texture that is the color you want, use that as your texture initially, and then change the mesh material to your final texture once the desired texture has fully loaded.

Comment: Option #1 works, but I would prefer the second one. However, I cannot figure out how to actually update the mesh material with the final texture.

Comment: Try set material.needsUpdate flag to true.

You can find more detail and examples in the Three.js wiki about how to update things with WebGLRenderer.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates